# Personal account to Service Mailbox for Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I have a Logic app for searching Application Secret expiration.

It is working good. Next week we will go to production level, the reason why I need to change from my Personal account to Service Mail box so that Notification can come to the Service Account not to my Personal Account.

So Responsible person can take a action

**Screenshot:**
[image]

How can i insert a Service Mailbox instead of my personal account?

Comment: Are you using Personal subscription or organisational subscription?

Comment: Have you consider using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendgrid/ ?

Comment: I am using Organization Subscription @rithwikbojja

Answer (score 0):

You can add the responsible person account in connection if the account is in same tenant. To do that you need to follow these steps.
[image]
[image]
select “**Use another account**”
[image]

Login with your credentials after successful login you will see your required account is added in connection.
[image]
Then select the account
[image]

If user is not available in same tenant, you can add the user to the tenant with the required access.
OR
you need to create the workflow/design in the Organization Subscription where you have the user available.